# How to convert a DataFrame using map, reduce , apply or other functions in python (in this example)?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, apply, reduce

I Have such DataFrame:
[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [111,222], 'CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime': ['27.04.2018', '09.06.2018'], 'CycleOfRepricing': ['3M','5M'] }) 
df['CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime'] ) 
df
```

I need to get such DataFrame:
[image]

The result DataFrame: the first column is id , the second column is Date with frequency equals 'CycleOfRepricing' of this id. 
Max date is 31.12.2019

I have tried to solve such task with apply, map, etc. But I have not had a success since I can get only objects

```
 df.apply(lambda x: \
        pd.date_range(start = x.CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime, \
                         end = pd.to_datetime('31.12.2019'),
                         freq = x.CycleOfRepricing), axis = 1)
```

I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to match day of the month for each period.

```
df.assign(ReportingTime=df.apply(lambda x: \
        pd.date_range(start = x.CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime, \
                         end = pd.to_datetime('31.12.2019'),
                         freq = x.CycleOfRepricing+'S')+
                                pd.Timedelta(days=x.CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime.day-1), 
                      axis = 1)).explode('ReportingTime').to_markdown()
```

Output:

```
|    |   id | CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime   | CycleOfRepricing   | ReportingTime       |
|---:|-----:|:-----------------------------|:-------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2018-05-27 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2018-08-27 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2018-11-27 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-02-27 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-05-27 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-08-27 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-11-27 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2018-10-06 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2019-03-06 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 |
```

Try this using pandas version 0.25.0+:

```
df.assign(ReportingTime=df.apply(lambda x: \
        pd.date_range(start = x.CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime, \
                         end = pd.to_datetime('31.12.2019'),
                         freq = x.CycleOfRepricing), axis = 1)).explode('ReportingTime')
```

Output:

```
|    |   id | CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime   | CycleOfRepricing   | ReportingTime       |
|---:|-----:|:-----------------------------|:-------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2018-04-30 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2018-07-31 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-01-31 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-04-30 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-07-31 00:00:00 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 | 2019-10-31 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2018-09-30 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2019-07-31 00:00:00 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same line, but got stuck because `ReportingTime` is always the last day of the month, but we need a specific day of the month.I was just looking at the `pandas.date_range` page, but could not find anything there (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Any suggestion?

Comment: @divingTobi Okay, I updated with some code... I am going to continue to search for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
def convert_my_df(dataframe, end):

    date, month, _id = ([] for x in range(3))

    x = list(dataframe['CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime'])
    y = list(dataframe['CycleOfRepricing'])
    z = list(dataframe['id'])
    end = pd.to_datetime(end)

    for i in range(dataframe.shape[0]):
        while x[i] < end:
            _id.append(z[i])
            month.append(y[i])
            n_months = int(y[i][0])
            x[i] += pd.DateOffset(months=n_months)
            date.append(x[i])

    new_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': _id, 'CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime': date, 'CycleOfRepricing': month})
    new_df = new_df[new_df['CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime'] <= end]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, dataframe]).sort_values(['id', 'CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime'])
    return new_df

print(convert_my_df(df, '2019-12-31').to_markdown())  #to_markdown() added in pandas 1.0.0
|    |   id | CycleOfRepricingAnchorTime   | CycleOfRepricing   |
|---:|-----:|:-----------------------------|:-------------------|
|  0 |  111 | 2018-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  0 |  111 | 2018-07-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  1 |  111 | 2018-10-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  2 |  111 | 2019-01-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  3 |  111 | 2019-04-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  4 |  111 | 2019-07-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  5 |  111 | 2019-10-27 00:00:00          | 3M                 |
|  1 |  222 | 2018-09-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 |
|  7 |  222 | 2019-02-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 |
|  8 |  222 | 2019-07-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 |
|  9 |  222 | 2019-12-06 00:00:00          | 5M                 |
```